# Is the "glory" that is spoken about in Exodus 40:34-35 a light that appeared in the Holy of holies?

Tags: hebrew, word-study, exodus, hebrew-bible, pneumatology

In the book [The School of Christ by T Austin Sparks](https://www.austin-sparks.net/english/books/001037.html) I read the following

> Looking backward at that tabernacle or that temple of old where the
>   **Shekinah glory** was found, we mark that **that light, that glory which
>   linked heaven and earth like a ladder, had its expression in the Most
>   Holy Place.** You know that in the Holy of Holies, everything was
>   curtained around and over, excluding every bit of natural light, so
>   that the place, entered into apart from the Shekinah, would have been
>   black darkness, without light at all; but entered into **while the glory
>   rested upon it, it was all light, it was all Divine light, heavenly
>   light, the light of God.**

An I read in the article [The Shekinah Glory](https://www.bible-history.com/tabernacle/TAB4The_Shekinah_Glory.htm) the following.

> The etymology of the dwelling or presence of God is the Hebrew word
>   **Sh'cheenah** or as we pronounce it **Shekinah**. The term Shekinah was many
>   times used interchangeably with the word God.

But in [Wikipedia article on Shekhinah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shekhinah) I read the following

> This term does not occur in the Bible, and is from rabbinic
>   literature.

and

> Kabbalah associates the shekhinah with the female.[9]:128,
>   n.51 According to Gershom Scholem, "The introduction of this idea was
>   one of the most important and lasting innovations of Kabbalism. ...no
>   other element of Kabbalism won such a degree of popular approval."[16]
>   The "feminine Jewish divine presence, the Shekhinah, distinguishes
>   Kabbalistic literature from earlier Jewish literature."[17]

1. Is the word **Sh'cheenah** or **Shekinah** used any where in the
   bible? The closest I have come across is 7931. [shakan or shaken](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/7931.htm) in  [Exodus 40:35](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/exodus/40-35.htm)
2. What does it refer to? Is it the Holy Spirit
3. How did it manifest? Is it some form of light?
4. Did that light come into the Holy of holies and was that the only light in the holy of holies?
5. Does it have anything to do with the **Shekinah** in the article
   [The Truth about Shekinah Glory](https://www.watchprophecyclub.com/programs/the-truth-about-shekinah-glory)
6. Does the scripture teach any feminine aspect of God as told by [Kenneth Copeland](https://www.kcm.org/za/node/15158)

Let me know if this question needs to be broken down.

Answer (score 1):

I will not comment about Leslie Johnson's views, nor Kenneth Copeland's views as this is a site about Biblical Hermeneutics.

I agree that neither "Shekinah" nor "Shekinah glory" appears in the Bible.  It is only described in Rabbinic literature.

The closest we come to this extra-biblical idea are three situations described in the following places:

1. At the dedication of the tabernacle in the wilderness when the "cloud" filled the tabernacle and the priests could not enter Ex 40:35, Heb 3:19.
2. The dedication of Solomon's temple when the same thing occurred 2 Chron 7:2, 1 Kings 8:11
3. A prophetic scene described in Rev 15:8 concerning the seven last plagues.

In all cases we have a cloud preventing the ministration of the priests because of the glory of the Lord.  None of these has any specific mention of the Holy Spirit in particular, only God generally (presumably meaning the entire Godhead but this is not specified.)  The only furniture in the Holy of Holies was the Ark of the Covenant which was not, itself, equipped with any light producing device.  So if there was light it must have come from something else, presumably, the presence of God with whom Moses spoke. Ex 25:32, 29:42, etc.

Comment: "cloud excluding" ? Could yo please clarify

Comment: My apologies - sentence clarified.